# how exactly package dependencies works?

Tags: package-management, dependencies

- How exactly package dependencies works when we are transferring
  packages from one PC to other?
- Is there anything else that influence on package dependencies?
- How exactly computer architecture matters for package dependency ?

After my small research on Google, I found
It dependent on

1)OS versions

2)computer architecture(*86 bit os system packages won't work on 62 bit      os vice versa)

Comment: a 64-bit system can run all 32-bit applications and it's still based on x86, it's just an extension, what's your sources?

Comment: Define "transferring packages from one PC to another"

Comment: @Alvar, yes, but the dependencies of a package must be the same arch as the package itself.  In other words, a 32 bit program needs the 32 bit version of the libraries it uses, not the 64 bit one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dependency occurs when one package depends on another. You might think it would make for an easier-to-manage system if no package depended on any others, but you’d face a few problems, not the least of which would be dramatically increased disk usage.

Packages on your Linux system depend on other packages. Just about every package with an application, for example, depends on the system C libraries, since these libraries provide common facilities that just about every program uses. Network applications typically depend on low-level networking libraries. These dependencies really work in your favor, since a security bug fix in the network libraries can update all applications that make use of the updated libraries.

Furthermore, sharing software means that each package has less code to maintain and thus improved quality. Code sharing has been in the computer lexicon since the 1960s.

Although quite a few packages depend on system-level libraries, some packages depend on applications defined in other packages. The Emacs text editor package, for example, depends on the Perl scripting language, specifically, the perl command. Database client programs usually depend on the database server applications.

An application may depend on a capability provided by another package. It may also depend on the capability that a specific version of another package provides.

Most package dependencies assume some level of compatibility and require a version at or above a given version number.

<sup>Source:FP</sup>